# prolog - finding max sum subtree of a binary tree

Tags: prolog

How can I find the max **sum** sub-tree of a binary tree in Prolog

let's say this is the tree:

```
t(t(t(nil,-5,nil),4,t(t(nil,15,nil),-20,t(nil,10,nil))),2,t(nil,-8,t(t(nil,9,nil),12,t(nil,10,nil))))
```

The maximum **sum** sub-tree of this tree is the right bottom tree:

```
t(t(nil,9,nil),12,t(nil,10,nil))
```

How can I find this in prolog?

Comment: You could start by writing some prolog to try and solve the problem.  Also by defining how you are determining which subtree is maximum.

Comment: @ScottHunter I wish I'd knew how to start writing solution to this problem. And as I wrote - the maximum *sum* sub-tree, how can I explain it better? the sub-tree which the sum of it's nodes is larger than all other sub-trees in the tree

Comment: You mention *max sub-tree* 3 times, only once adding the word *sum*.  And if you don't know how to write anything prolog, you should start by learning about the language.

Comment: I don't think the subtree in your example is the max because it has sum:31 but the t(t(nil,4,t(t(nil,15,nil),-20,t(nil,10,nil))),2,t(nil,-8,t(t(nil,9,nil),12,t(nil,10,nil)))) has sum  34 which is larger and it is obviously a subtree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write this:

```
 max_sub_tree(Tree,T,N):-
    sol_tree_noroot(Tree,T1,N1),
    sol_tree_withroot(Tree,T2,N2),!,
    max_set(T1,N1,T2,N2,T,N).

max_set(T1, N1, T2, N2, T, N) :-
    (N1>N2,T=T1,N=N1;
     N2>N1,T=T2,N=N2;
    N2=:=N1,N=N1,(T=T1;T=T2)).    

sol_tree_noroot(nil,nil,0).
sol_tree_noroot(t(L,_,R),T,N):-
      max_sub_tree(L,T1,N1),max_sub_tree(R,T2,N2),!,
      max_set(T1, N1, T2, N2, T, N).

sol_tree_withroot(nil,nil,0).
sol_tree_withroot(t(L,X,R),t(L1,X,R1),N3):-
     sol_tree_withroot(L,T1,N1),sol_tree_withroot(R,T2,N2),
     max_set2(T1,N1,T2,N2,L1,R1,N),
     N3 is N+X.

max_set2(T1,N1,T2,N2,L,R,N):-
    (N1>0,N2>0,N is N1+N2,L=T1,R=T2;
     N1>=0,N2<0,N is N1 ,R=nil,L=T1;
     N1<0,N2>=0,N is N2 ,L=nil,R=T2;
     N1<0,N2<0,N1<N2,N is N2 ,L=nil,R=T2;
     N1<0,N2<0,N1>N2,N is N1 ,L=T1,R=nil;
     N1>0,N2=0,N is N1,(L=T1,R=nil;L=T1,R=T2);
     N1=0,N2>0,N is N2,(R=T2,L=nil;L=T1,R=T2);
     N1=0,N2=0,N is N1,(L=T1,R=nil;R=T2,L=T1;L=T1,R=T2)).
```

when you call:

```
max_sub_tree(t(t(t(nil, -5, nil), 4, t(t(nil, 15, nil), -20, t(nil, 10, nil))), 2, t(nil, -8, t(t(nil, 9, nil),12,t(nil, 10, nil)))),T,N).
```

it returns:

```
T = t(t(nil, 4, t(t(nil, 15, nil), -20, t(nil, 10, nil))), 2, t(nil, -8, t(t(nil, 9, nil), 12, t(nil, 10, nil)))),
N = 34 ;
```

where T is the max subtree in your  given tree ,which has sum of nodes 34 (and not 31 as in your example).

Comment: sorry but... `max_sub_tree/3` in the final example is `sol_tree/3` in preceding code?

Comment: @max66 ,you have absolutely right ,I changed the name the last minute to be more descriptive and forgot to change it further up ,I edited my answer,thanks!!!

Comment: @coder you couldve just linked him to my thread from a few days back

Comment: @infested,this was a little different since it was asked to return a tree and not a list so i needed to change a few things in the implementation, but the main idea was the same .

Comment: @coder, nice idea for a different interpretation of the question, but the result sub-tree must be a sub-tree of the original tree. meaning you can't skip nodes just because they reduce the result. that's why the answer is 31, because the sub-tree of 9-12-10 is a real sub-tree of the original tree.

Comment: @Tom , the answer that i gave is a subtree it is not skipping  nodes, subtree is a subset of af a tree which is connected (and of course tree).In the answer the tree that i gave is a subtree.

Comment: @coder you are right, my mistake. nice!! I didn't event see this answer

Answer (score 2):

Mmmmhhhh...
Not sure to unserstand what do you mean with "max sum subtree" but... hope this helps

```
maxSubTree(nil, 0, 0, nil).

maxSubTree(t(T1, V0, T2), Sum, Sum, t(T1, V0, T2)) :-
  maxSubTree(T1, Sum1, MaxSum1, _),
  maxSubTree(T2, Sum2, MaxSum2, _),
  Sum is Sum1 + Sum2 + V0,
  Sum >= MaxSum1,
  Sum >= MaxSum2.

maxSubTree(t(T1, V0, T2), Sum, MaxSum1, MaxTree1) :-
  maxSubTree(T1, Sum1, MaxSum1, MaxTree1),
  maxSubTree(T2, Sum2, MaxSum2, _),
  Sum is Sum1 + Sum2 + V0,
  MaxSum1 >= Sum,
  MaxSum1 >= MaxSum2.

maxSubTree(t(T1, V0, T2), Sum, MaxSum2, MaxTree2) :-
  maxSubTree(T1, Sum1, MaxSum1, _),
  maxSubTree(T2, Sum2, MaxSum2, MaxTree2),
  Sum is Sum1 + Sum2 + V0,
  MaxSum2 >= Sum,
  MaxSum2 >= MaxSum1.
```

With

```
maxSubTree(t(t(t(nil,-5,nil),4,t(t(nil,15,nil),-20,t(nil,10,nil))),2,t(nil,-8,t(t(nil,9,nil),12,t(nil,10,nil)))), _, _, MT)
```

I obtain (variable `MT`)

```
t(t(nil,9,nil),12,t(nil,10,nil))
```